# Calibrating my camera with OpenCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, colors, computer-vision

I would like to apply a color map on a grayscale image,  with applyColorMap  but it seems that it doesn't take into consideration the IplImage pointers, according to :
http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html

What would be the right syntax for that?

Something else, is there a link between Camera Calibration and Color Mapping? Is it about the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a `cv::Mat` to `applyColorMap` according to the [ColorMaps page](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/colormaps.html) in the OpenCV documentation.

Looking at [this OpenCV C++ cheat sheet](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/c++_cheatsheet.html) we see that an `IplImage` can be converted to a `Mat` by simply passing the `IplImage` to the `Mat` constructor: `Mat imgMat(iplimg);`